# 1873 British use of 'which', as a relative pronoun?

Tags: difference, relative-pronouns

> [[25% down the page]](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ethics/capitalpunishment/against_1.shtml) In any case, is vengeance necessarily a bad thing?
>
> The Victorian legal philosopher [James Fitzjames Stephens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Fitzjames_Stephen) [in  *Liberty, Equality, Fraternity*] thought vengeance was an acceptable justification for punishment. Punishment, he thought, should be inflicted:
>
> > 1. for the sake of ratifying the feeling of hatred − call it revenge, resentment, or what you will − **which** the contemplation of such [offensive] conduct excites[,] in healthily constituted minds.

Would someone please explain **which**? What's this phenomenon called?

How does the above differ from the only way in which I could interpret this quote, by removing **which**:

> 2. for the sake of ratifying the feeling of hatred − call it revenge, resentment, or what you will. **The** contemplation of such [offensive] conduct **excites** in healthily constituted minds.

But 2 sounds wrong, because **excite** is a transitive verb (so 'excite in' is unreasoning)?

Update: I inserted a comma after 'excite', if this shos that '**which** ... excites' is the relative clause?

Comment: I would disagree that vengeance per se is the rationale for punishment.  It is a meta-rationale: the desire to ratify the feeling that people get when they behold someone doing wrong to *others*.

Answer (score 3):

> for the sake of ratifying the feeling of hatred − call it revenge, resentment, or what you will − which the contemplation of such [offensive] conduct excites in healthily constituted minds.

To make the sentence more understandable, I'd rather remove the parenthetic construction between the dashes:

> for the sake of ratifying the feeling of hatred which the contemplation of such [offensive] conduct excites in healthily constituted minds.

Hence

> The contemplation of such conduct excites the feeling of hatred in healthy minds. So, for the sake of ratifying this feeling, let us bestow punishment upon convicts.

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively. Is there a name for this issue? I want to practice reading more of such sentences.

Comment: Thanks for the thanks! I don't know if there's a name for such constructions.